# MVC Base Controller and Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am implementing Ninject dependency injection in an existing MVC 2 application that uses a base controller that all controllers inherit to set navigation and other information needed by the master page.  When I set a controller to inherit from the base controller, I get the following error: "...BaseController' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.  How do I get around this error? I am new to Ninject and can't figure this out.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private INavigationRepository navigationRepository;
        private ISessionService sessionService;


        public BaseController(INavigationRepository navigationRepository, IMembershipService membershipService, ISessionService sessionService)
        {
            this.navigationRepository = navigationRepository;
            this.sessionService = sessionService;
        }
    }


 public class HomeController: BaseController
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding that ctor is one way

```
public class HomeController: BaseController
{
    public HomeController(INavigationRepository navigationRepository, IMembershipService membershipService, ISessionService sessionService)
    : base(navigationRepository, membershipService, sessionService) { }

}
```

or property injection

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    public INavigationRepository navigationRepository { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public ISessionService sessionService { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Went with property injection.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Property injection is not cleaner. It's the other way round. You want to have the dependencies readonly whenever possible.

Comment: yes cleaner was the wrong word...it's more convenient in that you don't need to declare the ctor in all your controllers.